# LARAVEL 9 Target class does not exist

Tags: php, model-view-controller, orm

After creating a Model and a Controller using artisan and defining the action in the controller.
I created a route Route::get('/showStudents', 'StudentsController@index');

But the problem is the controller is not defined by laravel .
I checked the possibility of typos so many times , namespaces ,controller name ,model name
that path was so usefull , I asked a friend who said that channging the  controller name after creating it using artisan  makes that error , but thing is i recreated the controller name another time and i left the original name . But unfortunately that didn't help
thank in advance

controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class StudentsController extends Controller
{
    //
}
```

```
models

<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Students extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
public funtion index(){
echo 'hhh';
}
```

route

```
Route::get('/showStudents', 'StudentsController@index');
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 9.x Target class does not exist error at login application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72159986/laravel-9-x-target-class-does-not-exist-error-at-login-application)

Answer (score -2):

I tried this syntax in

```
[StudentsController::class, 'index']
```

instead of

```
'StudentsControlle@index '
```

and it worked.

Comment: I've edited your answer to read more like an answer (i.e. saying what you changed from/to) but I wasn't 100% sure about which bits were code. Please check what I've done and edit it if I did anything wrong.